# Dask.Series .mean().compute() results in "TypeError: _sum() got an unexpected keyword argument 'skipna' "

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dask

I do not grasp how the dask module uses lazy evaluations under the hood.
In the minimal example the numbers replaces a significant larger data set, hence the float64 (overflow).
What is the error in this "dask-like" syntax and why does it produces this (seemingly unrelated?) Error.

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
from dask import dataframe as dd

df = pd.DataFrame({'foo': [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]})
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=2)
```

In pandas I would do

```
In[1]: df['foo'].apply(np.float64).mean()
Out[1]: array([2.5, 3.5, 4.5])
```

What is the same as

```
In[2]: ddf['foo'].apply(np.float64, meta=('foo','f8')).compute().mean()
Out[2]: array([2.5, 3.5, 4.5])
```

as I evaluates first the pandas.Series and then calculating the mean.
If I want to make the whole calculation lazy I tried

```
In[3]: ddf['foo'].apply(np.float64, meta=('foo','f8')).mean().compute()
```

but I do not understand the TypeError.
The stack trace:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-8704408e68ef> in <module>
----> 1 ddf['foo'].apply(np.float64, meta=('foo','f8')).mean().compute()

~/miniconda3/envs/flash-hdf/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dask/base.py in compute(self, **kwargs)
    277         dask.base.compute
    278         """
--> 279         (result,) = compute(self, traverse=False, **kwargs)
    280         return result
    281 

~/miniconda3/envs/flash-hdf/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dask/base.py in compute(*args, **kwargs)
    559         postcomputes.append(x.__dask_postcompute__())
    560 
--> 561     results = schedule(dsk, keys, **kwargs)
    562     return repack([f(r, *a) for r, (f, a) in zip(results, postcomputes)])
    563 

~/miniconda3/envs/flash-hdf/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dask/threaded.py in get(dsk, result, cache, num_workers, pool, **kwargs)
     74                 pools[thread][num_workers] = pool
     75 
---> 76     results = get_async(
     77         pool.apply_async,
     78         len(pool._pool),

~/miniconda3/envs/flash-hdf/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dask/local.py in get_async(apply_async, num_workers, dsk, result, cache, get_id, rerun_exceptions_locally, pack_exception, raise_exception, callbacks, dumps, loads, **kwargs)
    485                         _execute_task(task, data)  # Re-execute locally
    486                     else:
--> 487                         raise_exception(exc, tb)
    488                 res, worker_id = loads(res_info)
    489                 state["cache"][key] = res

~/miniconda3/envs/flash-hdf/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dask/local.py in reraise(exc, tb)
    315     if exc.__traceback__ is not tb:
    316         raise exc.with_traceback(tb)
--> 317     raise exc
    318 
    319 

~/miniconda3/envs/flash-hdf/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dask/local.py in execute_task(key, task_info, dumps, loads, get_id, pack_exception)
    220     try:
    221         task, data = loads(task_info)
--> 222         result = _execute_task(task, data)
    223         id = get_id()
    224         result = dumps((result, id))

~/miniconda3/envs/flash-hdf/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dask/core.py in _execute_task(arg, cache, dsk)
    119         # temporaries by their reference count and can execute certain
    120         # operations in-place.
--> 121         return func(*(_execute_task(a, cache) for a in args))
    122     elif not ishashable(arg):
    123         return arg

~/miniconda3/envs/flash-hdf/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dask/utils.py in apply(func, args, kwargs)
     29 def apply(func, args, kwargs=None):
     30     if kwargs:
---> 31         return func(*args, **kwargs)
     32     else:
     33         return func(*args)

~/miniconda3/envs/flash-hdf/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dask/dataframe/core.py in _reduction_aggregate(x, aca_aggregate, **kwargs)
   6289     if isinstance(x, list):
   6290         x = pd.Series(x)
-> 6291     return aca_aggregate(x, **kwargs)
   6292 
   6293 

~/miniconda3/envs/flash-hdf/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dask/utils.py in __call__(self, obj, *args, **kwargs)
    895 
    896     def __call__(self, obj, *args, **kwargs):
--> 897         return getattr(obj, self.method)(*args, **kwargs)
    898 
    899     def __reduce__(self):

TypeError: _sum() got an unexpected keyword argument 'skipna'
```

If you could provide me with a hint to where find the answer, it would really helpful!

---

Python 3.8.6
Numpy 1.19.4
Dask 2021.01.0
Pandas 1.1.4